# Python if-else clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to build a rule that states if email ID in `list_1` then send to **mail1@mail.com** and if email ID in `list_2` then send to **mail2@mail.com**

```
list_1 = ['abc@mail.com','def@mail.com']
list_2 = ['123@mail.com','456@mail.com']
if recipients in list_1:
    cc_list = 'mail1@mail.com'
else:
    cc_list = 'mail2@mail.com'
```

However I see the above always sends out the mail to `mail1@mail.com` even if the recipient is in list_2

Comment: Is "recipients" a list?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, recipients is an email address but I am trying to check if it exists in a list namely list_1 or list_2

Comment: You should indent your code better. In Python it's more important than just good standards.

Comment: Use logger or print the value of the recipients.  Due to your logic, anything that not found in list_1 will default to list_2 value. In fact, this is incorrect logic.

Comment: It is strange that it always defaults to `mail1@mail.com` - which should only be evaluated to `True` if `recipients in list_1`. Can you provide an example of the `recipients` that you have tried?

Comment: Can you explain what `recipients` is?

Comment: @coldspeed, recipients is an email address. It is an email address that exists in either list_1 or list_2

Comment: And cc_list is not actually a list?

Comment: @coldspeed, cc_list is just an email address.. list_1 and list_2 are lists. I managed to fix the problem by using the same code I pasted in my initial post but passing the output cc_list to a variable and calling it while writing the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'll explain why

Your if statement look only in list one

```
if recipients in list_1 #The If statement will check only list_1
```

So it doesn't look at inside the 2 liste
Keep in mind that if statement work this way

```
for item in list:
  if conditional:
      expression
```

So you need a boolean that look in both list then use the if statement